# Atualizar a SeekBar conforme toca o audio

Tags: android

Criei uma `seekBar` para ver o progresso do meu áudio que está rodando no `MediaPlayer`, porém de todos os métodos que utilizei para atualizar a `seekBar`, o único que funcionou foi esse abaixo:

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mySeekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
```

Todos os demais, como por exemplo, os que cito abaixo, não funcionaram.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mySeekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
        }
    }, 1000);
```

---

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                mySeekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

---

```
    new Thread(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                runOnUiThread(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mySeekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
                    }
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Assim, gostaria de saber porque os demais não funcionam, pois, para mim, todos deveriam funcionar. Aqui está o código completo do app:

```
package com.gabrielm.testseekbar;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SeekBar mySeekBar;
    Button btnPlay;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mySeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mySeekBar);
        btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sleep);

        mySeekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());

        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mySeekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
            }
        }, 0, 1000);

        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });



        mySeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                Log.i("Audio position", Integer.toString(progress));
                mp.seekTo(progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codigo 1:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mySeekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Não faz o que você pretende porque o *SeekBar* só é actualizado uma vez, [postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) executa o `Runnable r` uma vez com um *delay* de 1000 milisegundos.

Isso pode ser resolvido adicionando novamente o *Runnable* à *queue* dentro do método `run()`:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mySeekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Código 2:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            mySeekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Não funciona porque o código nunca é executado: falta chamar o método `start()` da *Thread*.
Resolvido isso também não funcionaria porque só é permitido alterar *Views* na *UIThread*.
Por outro lado o método `run()` só seria chamado uma vez.

Código 3:

```
new Thread(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            runOnUiThread(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mySeekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
                }
            });
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

O código não compila, o construtor de *Thread* recebe um *Runnable* e não um *TimerTask*.
Tal como no código 2 falta chamar o método `start()`, além que também só funcionaria uma vez, no entanto, resolve a questão da *UIThread*, recorrendo ao método `runOnUiThread()`.